# How do I publish a Git Repository from within Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013

I have a local repository with a master branch that works fine.  I would like to publish the Repository to a folder called C:\Users\bgreer\Dropbox\Development\Repos\Tooling.  I went into this folder and did a Git init.  Exactly how do I publish or push my local repository to the C:\Users\bgreer\Dropbox\Development\Repos\Tooling folder within VS2013 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the TeamExplorer Window there are a few Buttons, one labeled "Unsynced Commits" press it and Input the URL or Path of the remote repository and voila

If you can't Input a remote Location, it's probably because you already have one inserted. In that case go to the .git Folder and edit the config file in a Notepad remove the remote entry and hit refresh in the teamexplorer window within vs

VS2013 however only supports bare repositories as Folders use `git init --bare` to create one if you haven't done so.